# Display sum of item quantity in PDF export

Tags: php

I'm having issues displaying total quantity of all items at the bottom of my PDF export script I'm using with my Wordpress site.

I've been able to display total quantity of each item using

```
<td class="qty"><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_quantity() ) ?></td>
```

Then I want to calculate the sum of all item quantities and show that as a single figure at the bottom of the table

Would I use

```
echo sum_array ( $item->get_quantity() )
```

Comment: I hope you are showing each quantity via some loop, if yes then before loop define a variable like `$sum = 0;`, now change `<td>` code like this: `<td class="qty"><?php $sum += (int)$item->get_quantity(); echo esc_html( $item->get_quantity() ) ?></td>`, and now in the end use this `$sum` variable to show total quantity

Comment: Awesome, will re-write it now and test. Yes it's shown via a loop

Comment: I'm completely stumped - I used the above but it's displaying a figure which doesn't represent the total. I've pasted my script here - edit is line 344
https://pastebin.com/ZxAGUsdi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are showing each quantity via some loop, if yes then before loop define a variable like

```
$sum = 0;
```

Now change `<td>` code like this (inside loop):

```
<td class="qty">
  <?php 
     $sum += (int)$item->get_quantity(); 
     echo esc_html( $item->get_quantity() ) ?>
</td>
```

And now in the end use this `$sum` variable to show total quantity.

```
<?php echo $sum;?>
```

Comment: I'm completely stumped - I used the above but it's displaying a figure which doesn't represent the total. I've pasted my script here - edit is line 344 pastebin.com/ZxAGUsdi

Comment: @TomHutchison  glad that solution worked for you....

Comment: It's displaying a different total though, can you take a look at line 344 and say where I went wrong?

Comment: @TomHutchison As i said quantity addition code will goes to each `<td>` inside loop, your code is too big to check. You have to correct yourself. What I can see is you have added all code in the end. Please check/read my edited solution.